# How to make a proper server tick?

Tags: python, timing

I am trying to make a game server which updates after a certain period.

```
import time
last_time = time.time()
tick = 1
time_since_last_update = 0
while True:
    new_time = time.time()
    dt = new_time - last_time
    time_since_last_update += dt
    last_time = new_time
    if time_since_last_update > tick:
        print("Magic happens")
        time_since_last_update = 0
```

When I do this thing, python consumes 100% computing power on one of the cores. I don't really understand why is this happening and how to fix this if possible.

Comment: from what I understand is that you want to print this after every 1 second right?

Comment: It's just a stub. My idea is to do updates each second without doing `time.sleep(1)`

Comment: If you don't do that then this loop will run at the 100% utilization, and keep on incrementing with tiny values till it reaches 1. Don't make that core run so hard, please! it's not fair.

Comment: @harshil9968 that's why I'm asking this question. But again, `time.sleep(1)` is not an option.

Comment: I don't think any other option will be as good as `time.sleep(1)`, why do you want to something else can you explain?

Comment: When I wrote my version of a snake game, `time.sleep(period)` completely spoiled gameplay. So now I'm trying to avoid it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120604/discussion-between-harshil9968-and-montreal).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Insert a `time.sleep(0.01)` to wait 10 millis between each time poll otherwise your loop polls time continuously without releasing power to the cpu.

Edit: That is better, only waits once if needed. Should a huge CPU overload occur, the time to wait could be negative, and in that case 2 actions could be triggered at once.
And targeted time is recomputed constantly to avoid float accumulation errors.

```
import time
start_time = time.time()
tick = 1.0  # 1 second

tick_count = 0

while True:
    new_time = time.time()
    tick_count += 1
    targeted_time = start_time + tick*tick_count

    time_to_wait = targeted_time - new_time

    if time_to_wait>0:
        time.sleep(time_to_wait)
    print("Magic happens,waited %f seconds" % time_to_wait)
```

Comment: This is better than a busy loop but it probably isn't quite what the OP wanted. What they're probably looking for is code that will do everything they need to in that tick and then calculate how long to sleep until the next tick is due.

Comment: You are right. The sleep time should be predicted but that is the same principle

Comment: @WillKunkel It's not entirely a [busy loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting) as the python thread sleeps when `time.sleep()` is called. This allows other processes (or threads) to use the processor time.

Comment: @Aaron I said it was better than a busy loop, not that it was a busy loop.

Comment: @WillKunkel oops, my bad... Haven't had my coffee yet this morning xP

Comment: I have added an example which only waits when needed. Much better.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, whoa! Actually both solutions are working but I found latter more elegant. Thank you very much!

Comment: you're welcome. I haven't coded a lot of retro-games in various languages (with always the same timer problematic) for nothing. Some platforms/APIs have a timer callback but using such mechanisms make your code less portable between platform/versions.

Comment: Now I am just warming up, writing client-server snake game with web-sockets. Next time I'll do something more interesting.

Comment: Looks like variable `time_since_last_update` is not required in this code.